# Why we need more reputation to add tags in our question

Tags: discussion, tags

I have posted my [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/219483/calculating-milliseconds-using-timers-in-pic-and-synchronizing-it-with-ds1307-ti). As it was about timing and `DS1307`, so I wanted to add tag `DS1307` but then it says you need to 300+ reputation for that tag. I don't know the meaning of this rule. I think we should be able to tag our question as we want.

Why tags require reputation.?

Comment: Because we can't let people nilly willy add tags. They come with some maintenance effort, and we want to document them properly (tag wiki) and prevent duplicates (tags that really mean the same). They lose their value if we don't try to create only those that are searched for.

Comment: For exactly this situation. It doesn't accomplish anything to have a tag for every IC.

Comment: Tags are for categorization, not information.  Is DS1307 a good category for the site, or is it too narrow?  If you spend more time participating postively in the site -- for which rep is a good proxy -- you'll be able to answer that question.

Comment: I think maybe OP doesn't understand that she is creating a tag rather than adding an existing one?

Answer (score 5):

If anyone could add whatever silly tag popped into their minds, we'd have a lot of silly tags.

The Stack Exchange system takes some getting used to, and rep is used as a metric for how much you likely know about the system.  People that don't yet understand how the system works need to be prohibited from making a mess.

This case is a great example.  You clearly haven't taken the time to learn the SE system and how tags are supposed to work, yet tried to create one.  Common sense (*"I'm new here, so if something doesn't look right, I'll assume the problem is my understanding of it."*) should be good enough to prevent that, but all too often people are arrogant (*"I'm new here and don't understand how everything works and what the norms here are, but eh, I just want to get my problem solved so I'll do what is expedient for me.  Screw the system and all these dweebs here.  I'll probably never be back, so what do I care if I leave a path of destruction behind me?"*) and won't take the trouble to learn and do things carefully.  Therefore users must have some minimum experience level, measured in rep, to do things that can damage the system.  Looks like it worked.

Frankly, 300 rep seems like a really low bar for creating new tags.  That should probably be 1000 or so.

Comment: I agree that this privilege has too low a bar - too many stupid typo tags.

Comment: @W5VO  On StackOverflow the ability to create new tags turns on at [1500 reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags).

Answer (score 3):

But what happens when the next person wants to use the DS1308 chip?

What if someone wanted to use the TLE2021 OPAMP and tag. And then someone wanted to tag for TLE2022, TLE2024 ... what about purchasing variance ... TLE2024BCDW, TLE2024MN  etc

Where would the madness end.

Or simply group together the DS130* as **RTC/Timer** and the TLE as **OPAMP's**